who to get email of githubUser whit firebase auth
I try to creat diary app and i need to stor data of my user whit there mail on firebase data .
to log theme i need to use authProvider of flutter i allready did it for googl whit GoogleSignIn
but for githubauthprovider it dosn't work .
i use android i don't know if it rly matter but i say it .
i just copy past the firebase documentation .
  void _handleGithubSignIn() async {
    GithubAuthProvider githubProvider = GithubAuthProvider();
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(githubProvider);
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to sign in with GitHub: $e');
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

am i supose to do a request to https://api.github.com/user/emails ? and if it s only way to make it work where i supose to find the authorization token ?
i find a topic where it s say it s cose my github mail is private so i set it in public and it change nhoting . (also i want user whitout public mail can connect .
